# Критично ли влияет большое количество повторяющегося js-кода на скорость загрузки страницы?

Tags: php, javascript

На сайте интернет магазина, на странице "Все товары", в каждом товаре в теге script присутствует такой код:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#buy10769').blur(
        function (){
           $.ajax({
               url: "/include/section/add-easy-cart.php",
               type: "POST",
               data: ({id : 10769, quantity : this.value}),  
               success: function(res)  {
               }
           });

          if ($("#buy10769").val()>0) {
          document.getElementById('reload-cart').click();
       }

    });
});
```

Товаров на странице 540. Критично ли для загрузки страницы такое количество скриптов?

Comment: @TotalPusher Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Во первых** - ваша страница тяжелая, в прямом смысле. Ваш код весит определенное кол-во байт, причем у вас 540 раз повторяется такой скрипт

**Во вторых** - когда парсер HTML доходит до тега скрипт, он начнет разбирать его, блокируя парсинг остального `html`, опять же у вас 540 раз он будет парсить почти что одинаковый код

У вас на странице куча одинаковых элементов ( допустим инпуты )

```
<input id='#buy10769' class='buy-input' data-id='10769' />
<input id='#buy10770' class='buy-input' data-id='10770' />
<input id='#buy10771' class='buy-input' data-id='10771' />
```

И ваш код, можно его модифицировать

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.buy-input').blur(
        function () {
           const $this = $(this)
           const id = $this.attr('data-id')
           const value = $this.val()
           $.ajax({
               url: "/include/section/add-easy-cart.php",
               type: "POST",
               data: ({id, quantity : value}),  
               success: function(res)  {}
           });

          if (value > 0) {
             document.getElementById('reload-cart').click();
          }
        }
    });
});
```

Теперь вместо 540а вариантов вашего скрипта, у нас есть один. Который вешает обработчики событий на каждый инпут, можно обойтись без `data-id`, тогда просто `id` сделать в виде `10769`

Comment: Огромное спасибо за ответ и за скрипт!
Проверил на этом примере скорость загрузки.

С очисткой кэша страница грузилась 18.5 сек
С подгруженным кэшем 10 сек
+ Была недоступна для кликов, торомозила, отрисовывала дерево еще секунд 15

После удаления скриптов торзмозов и долгого рендеринга не замечено. 
Без кэша - 8сек.
С кэшем - 5.3 сек.